# Ruby min max assignment operators

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, max, assignment-operator, min

When programming ruby I always find myself doing this:

```
a = [a, b].min
```

This means compare `a` and `b` and store the smallest value in `a`. I don't like writing the code above as I have to write `a` twice.

I know that some non-standard dialects of C++ had an operator which did exactly this

```
a <?= b
```

Which I find very convenient. But I'm not really interested in the operator as much as I'm in the *feature of avoiding repetition*. I would also be happy if I could write

```
a.keep_max(b)
```

`a` can be a quite long variable, like `my_array[indice1][indice2]`, and you don't want to write that twice.

I did alot of googling on this and found no result, hopefully this question will pop up and be useful for others aswell.

So, is there any non-repeitive way to express what I want in ruby?

Comment: IMO re-binding values (without an excellent reason for doing it) is a bad choice, just create a new variable with a different name. Think about it: now `a` has value 2, now some magic, `a` has value 1... that kind of code is harder to understand and debug. But, of course, I am a functional bigot ;-)

Comment: @tokland, yea perhaps. But for typical dynamic programming code, say floyd-warshall, you often do exactly what I expressed. After all assignments can be the power of imperative languages.

Comment: Fair enough, when you are inside an imperative loop you have no option but to reuse variable names (and I guess a functional implementation of that algorithm may be inefficent in Ruby). My note was just a prevention against lazy coding that reuses variable names just because.

Comment: @tokland, Yep. what you say is completely right. I'm a haskell fan, but I believe assignments are not always evil! Furthermore ruby isn't primarily designed for functional style (afaik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would like to do is in fact not possible in ruby ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130994/generic-way-to-replace-an-object-in-its-own-method)). I think the best you can do is

```
def max(*args)
  args.max
end

a = max a, b
```

Comment: The correct answer seems indeed to be that it simply isn't possible without `eval` tricks (which another question mentioned, thanks @kentor).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question. You can always do something like this ...

```
module Comparable
  def keep_min(other)
     (self <=> other) <= 0 ? self : other
  end

  def keep_max(other)
     (self <=> other) >= 0 ? self : other
  end
end

1.keep_min(2)
=> 1

1.keep_max(2)
=> 2
```

Well, that won't work for all objects with <=> because not all of them are implementing Comparable, so you could monkey-patch Object.

Personally I prefer clarity and tend to avoid monkey-patching. Plus, this clearly is a *binary predicate*, just like "+", therefore method-chaining doesn't necessarily make sense so I prefer something like this to get rid of that array syntax:

```
def min(*args)
   args.min
end

def max(*args)
   args.max
end

min(1, 2)
=> 1

max(1, 2)
=> 2
```

But hey, I'm also a Python developer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own method for it:

```
class Object
  def keep_max(other)
    [self, other].max
  end
end

a = 3
b = 7
puts a.keep_max(b)
```

But you should be careful defining methods on Object as it can have unpredictable behaviour (for example, if objects cannot be compared).

Answer (score 0):

```
def keep_max(var, other, binding)
  eval "#{var} = [#{var}, #{other}].max", binding
end

a = 5 
b = 78
keep_max(:a, :b, binding)
puts a
#=> 78
```

This basically does what you want. Take a look at [Change variable passed in a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905010/change-variable-passed-in-a-method)

Comment: `eval` and `binding` for a `keep_max`, I would not recommend doing that